# getting information out of result set while

Tags: jdbc

I made a project database for my class called amazon.
In this report I want to display fromt the best selled product to the last selled.
I want to get the toppest selled product and display all the custumers who purchased them
and display and their email and the quantanty they purched of that product.
Okay , I can totaly display the best selled products. And I know how to get the the first row ( I'll have a problem if two or more products have the same number of sells) but I can't just get the title from the first table out of the result set while to make the other query :/
Can anyone help me to solv this problem?

```
void report2 (Connection conn) 
        throws SQLException, IOException {

String query0 = "select title, SUM (quantityb) AS total from product,buy where id = idb group by title order by total DESC";


String title,title2,name,email,t;
int quan,quanp;

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement (); 
ResultSet rset0;

System.out.print("\n\n************************************MOST POPULAR PRODUCTS************************************\n");

System.out.print("         TITLE OF THE PRODUCT                                                TOTAL PURCHASED\n"+
         "--------------------------------------------                            -------------------------\n");



try {
rset0 = stmt.executeQuery(query0);
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Problem reading purchases");
    while (e != null) {
    System.out.println("Message     : " + e.getMessage());
    e = e.getNextException();
    }
    return;
}
while (rset0.next())
{

    title = rset0.getString(1);
    quan = rset0.getInt(2);


    System.out.printf("%-108s   %-3d \n ",title,quan);
}



PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query0);
statement.setMaxRows(1);
ResultSet rset1 = statement.executeQuery();
while (rset0.next())
{

  title2= rset1.getString(1);

}


   String query2 = "select  
   String query1 = "Select fname,email,quantityb"+
                  "from custumer,product,buy"+
                  "where email = emailb"+
                  "and id = idb"+
                  "and title ='"+title2+"'";



System.out.print("..............................Who Purchased the most popular product.............................\n");

System.out.print("PRODUCT:"+title2+"\n\n");
System.out.print("     FIRST NAME                      EMAIL                 QUANTITY\n"+
         "---------------------    -----------------------------  ------------------\n");

ResultSet rset2;

try {
rset2= stmt.executeQuery(query1);

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Problem reading people");
    while (e != null) {
    System.out.println("Message     : " + e.getMessage());
    e = e.getNextException();
    }
    return;
}

while (rset2.next())
{

   name=rset2.getString(1);
   email=rset2.getString(2);
   quanp=rset2.getInt(3);


    System.out.printf("%-8s \t\t\t%-25s\t\t\t %3d \n ",name,email,quanp);
}




stmt.close();
}
```

RESULT

commerce.java:405: variable title2 might not have been initialized
                      "and title ='"+title2+"'";
                                     ^
1 error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a homework or exercise.

```
variable title2 might not have been initialized
```

is because you have not initialized any of the string variable including `title2`

Change

`String title,title2,name,email,t;`  To

`String title="", title2="", name="", email="", t="";`.

Second,

```
String query2 = "select
```

This is incomplete and it should be something meaningful value with ending quote and semicolon.

Like `String query2 = "select  * from tblName";`

On a Side note,
Always provide full error stack with the question.